# Change related products from observer, when there are no related products

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, product-collection, related-products

I'm writing an extension that dynamically change related products, eg decide which related products to show during page load.

Basically I listen to the catalog_product_collection_load_after event, temper with the collection, and let Magento cerry on. this works great for products that have related products to show and I just override them.

Unfortunately, someone at Magento though it was real smart to NOT emit the "catalog_product_collection_load_after" for whatever reason, so I can't do this with products that have no related products at all.

Also, I don't like this method because it load useless products which I override anyway.

Looking at the related products code (Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related) it will be quite challenging to edit the collection from outside. Even if I change the collection the block will just overwrite it in _prepareData. So I need to somehow catch it right after the lines:

```
$this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter()
        ;
```

And before its actually rendered.

I also tried to listen to core_layout_block_create_after event and dynamically push a single related product just so the event will be emitted and I can override it, but it didn't work. I tried to push it like this:

```
$data=array("560"=>array('position'=>1));
$product->setRelatedLinkData($data);
```

Any tips or ideas how can I manage to push my own related products from extension **even** when product have no related products?

**Note:** I don't want to actually edit the DB. It must be pushed dynamically from some observer.

Thanks!